# An image drawn by drawimage on top of Swing application flikers and not stable

Tags: java, swing, drawimage

I have a Swing Java application, the interface consists of a mainframe, menuBar that contains many drop menus. At the top right corner, I draw a logo using drawImage(). the logo spans over the menuBar and the mainPanel as well.

When I open some(not all) components from the drop down menus in the menuBar, the logo starts to appear/disappear(flash).

The idea to put the logo as an icon for JLabel and add the JLabel to a panel does not work with me because I want the logo to span over the menubar and part of the mainpanel.

Comment: What is your question?  Where is your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Please post some code that we can look at.

Answer (score 0):

Split the logo into several sub-images (sprites) and add each to a label.

Comment: How would I add the first upper half to the top right of a JMenuBar ?

Comment: Either override  `paintComponent()` or try to set a custom border which paints the image as the right border.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the feedback.